# Create and add cookie by c# in .net framework 4.8 does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm new to C# and .net and have written a code in order to create a cookie
using this code:

```
HttpCookie userInfo = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
userInfo["userName"] = "user1";
userInfo["logdata"] = "data1";
userInfo.Expires.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
```

I want to add this cookie to the browser cookies with specific URI, so that the back-end code can see my new added cookie and read the data in theat cookie.
I have used this code:

```
myURI = new Uri(strURI);
request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myURI);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(myURI);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(userInfo);
```

When debugging I got error on this line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(userInfo);
```

telling that Response is null.
Could you please tell me was that correct? How to add a new created cookie to the browser?

Comment: No, did not answer my question. I want to know what is the command needed to set/ add the cookie created. AppendCookie was just a try and i'm not sure if  it is the right one

Comment: This could be of help for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885352/passing-cookies-in-response-redirect-in-asp-net

Comment: I m working with c# in .net framework4.8 and that solution on the link did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you're trying to add a cookie outside of a web environment. You need to make sure you're doing this within a valid HTTP context, like in an MVC controller or an ASP.NET web page.

An example in an MVC controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpCookie userInfo = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
        userInfo["userName"] = "user1";
        userInfo["logdata"] = "data1";
        userInfo.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

        Response.SetCookie(userInfo);

        return View();
    }
}
```

If you're in a different context, like an ASPX page, you can use `Response.Cookies.Add(userInfo)` instead of `Response.SetCookie(userInfo)`.

Comment: when using:         Response.SetCookie(userInfo);
i got error message: Response does not exist in the current context. Which API should i use for the object Response?

Comment: It did not work in c# with framework4.8

Comment: Did you make sure that is the right context?

Comment: what do you mean with right context? could you please show an example. as i write i'm new to the web programing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The "right context" refers to the environment in which your code is running. In the example you provided, it seems like you're trying to use the Response object outside of a web environment, which is why you're encountering the error message "Response does not exist in the current context."

If you're using this code in a console application or a class library, you won't have access to the Response object directly because it's specific to web applications.