# What are the differences between sending a redirect on the client side and one on the server side?

Tags: http, redirect

I was recently reviewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694089/sending-browser-cookies-during-a-302-redirect), and that post generated a doubt. What is the difference between sending a redirect as shown below versus sending a server side redirect?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=1; url="/example">
```

Is it the same to make a redirect using the html code shown above as using any programming language? When should I use each one? Thank you in advance :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP Location header and 3xx responses are supported by more clients, and allow you to give more information about the nature of the redirect (permanent/temporary), why the redirect happened (moved document, or 'see other').

The only case where you'll want to use the HTML `meta` tag is if the HTTP redirect can't be used.