# How do I do a redirect with cookies in the response header in a .net web api?

Tags: .net, angular, saml

I have an angular website which is authenticating through a third party IDP. The third party IDP logs the user in then sends a SAML response to my web API endpoint.

How can I have my API endpoint set a cookie for authentication and send the user back to my angular website with the cookie in the response header? Both the web app and API are on the same domain.

For example:

1. The user goes to https://mytestsite.com and presses Login.
2. The angular app uses a http.get call to send the user to my API endpoint https://mytestsite.com/api/auth/login.
3. The API endpoint creates a SAML request url and sends it to the user with using return Ok(url).
4. The Angular app then does a window.location.href = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/......" to send the user to the IDP.
5. The user is redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com/...... from the angular app.
6. The user logs into the third party IDP.
7. The user is redirected to my api at https://mytestsite.com/api/SamlConsumer
8. The web api validates the user, uses HttpContext.SignInAsync to create the cookie and redirects the user back to https://mytestsite.com.
9. When redirecting to https://mytestsite.com I open the chrome debugger tools and see that the response headers are blank. The Set-Cookies from the API is gone.

Steps 1-7 work great. I am able to send the user to authenticate and read back the SAML response. I am also then able to create the cookie. However, since the SAML response goes to a HttpPost API endpoint which then uses a RedirectResult to send the user back to my angular site, the cookie does not get added to the response header.

How can I get that cookie added to the response header in the API and sent to the angular app to send back and forth to authenticate the user while they use the site?

Comment: What language is your API build in?

Comment: The APIs are in .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the cookie to hold server details is not something you should do in FrontEnd(FE)/angular, but on the BackEnd (BE)/API instead.

In your step 8, the BE needs to set the required auth cookie so your FE/Browser can use it this further requests.

Still at it, if the redirect does not have the cookies:

Verify if you are using a custom header, you will need to configure the BE to allow the browser to read/store it:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("YourCorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowCredentials()
          ... // your other CORS configs
               .WithExposedHeaders("Your-Custom-Header");
    });
});
```

And you might also want to confugure the cookie options with `SameSite=Lax` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19948199/4604645).

Hopefully this sets you on the right track.